# Laravel Herd Nginx always redirect 301 when local site development is secured using herd secure and shared to public with ngrok

Tags: nginx, ngrok, laravel-herd

I'am new in using herd and I have this problem with sharing my laravel project using ngrok, since my project is using https, when shared using herd unsecure, my site got mixed content error, that causing the css and js won't load. When using herd secure, ngrok redirect the url to 301 infinitely.

using exposes is the same, but the different is it's work perfectly even using http, but exposes in free plan only have 1 hour lifetime. Is there a way to make https work with laravel herd shared via ngrok?

The way I share to ngrok is using

```
herd share
```

in the website folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to switch ngrok from expose

```
herd share-tool ngrok
```

After that you have to run following command to share

```
herd share
```

Comment: Hi, I did change herd share-tool to ngrok, and unfortunately the problem still persist. 
But somehow it's work today, I don't know what really happen haha. I just update the PHP version from 7.* to 8.* in Herd.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked also set your servers base url .

```
ngrok http https://forms.test --host-header=rewrite
```